# Save binary data to mongodb nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Currently I am saving specific data to mongodb as a string

```
var model = new Model({
    data: req.body.data,
    ...
});
```

and the model looks like this

```
var schema = new Schema({
    'data': {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    ...
});
```

Lets say the data looks like this: `00110111 00000001 01110100 10101101 00000001 00100111`. Is there a way i could save it as binary data? In this case this would only take up 6 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

**try use BSON format**

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var BSON = mongodb.BSON;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your model type is `Buffer`, then MongoDB will save it as `binData`